# special form or macro? eval-when-compile, eval-and-compile

Tags: help, elisp-macros, manual

Is `eval-when-compile` a special form (primitive in C), or a macro?

According to the elisp manual, `C-h S eval-when-compile RET`,

> Special Form: eval-when-compile body...

But according to `C-h f eval-when-compile RET`,

> eval-when-compile is a Lisp macro in ‘byte-run.el’

I'm trying to understand the difference between `eval-when-compile` and `eval-and-compile`. They have identical macro definitions in byte-run.el, but since the manual says they're special forms, rather than macros, I suspect there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a macro defined in `byte-run.el`:

```lisp
(defmacro eval-when-compile (&rest body)
  "Like `progn', but evaluates the body at compile time if you're compiling.
Thus, the result of the body appears to the compiler as a quoted
constant.  In interpreted code, this is entirely equivalent to
`progn', except that the value of the expression may be (but is
not necessarily) computed at load time if eager macro expansion
is enabled."
  (declare (debug (&rest def-form)) (indent 0))
  (list 'quote (eval (cons 'progn body) lexical-binding)))
```

I've submitted (doc) [bug #47862](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=47862) for this.